# getting a section of a string

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have an email address string such as `"John Smith" <JSmith@gmail.com>` and all I want is to get the email address inside the `<>`

How would I do that while not getting everything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're dealing with standard format email addresses ([RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)) you might want to consider using the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). The code for what you want is simple with it. E.g., assuming `input` contains your email address string:

```
String email = new InternetAddress(input).getAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a good way to go (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/)

Or you could just work with substrings...

Something along the lines of...

```
public static String getEmail(String x) {
    int firstBracket = 0;
    int secondBracket = 0;

    firstBracket = x.indexOf("<");
    secondBracket = x.indexOf(">");
    return x.substring(firstBracket+1, secondBracket);
}
```

Not necessarily the most robust solution... but it should do the job if the form is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions.  Something like this?

```
String name = "John Smith <smith@example.com>";
String email = name.replaceFirst(".*<(.*?)>.*","$1");
```